# When i converting my Py file to exe i am getting "[1516]Failed to execute script" error

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am using this command on cmd:

```
pyinstaller --onefile "Tkinter Final".py
```

Then it is converting to exe, but when I want to launch `.exe` file i am getting the error:

[This is the image shows the error](https://imge.to/i/87ESx)

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642520) solve your problem?

Comment: Try to use Python 3.6 in your environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with adding these before importing pandas

```
import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy
```

Edit : You can use this method too, on the cmd :

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import="numpy.random.common" --hidden-import="numpy.random.bounded_integers" --hidden-import="numpy.random.entropy" yourfilename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding `numpy.random` to the hidden import will work.

[Documentation about hidden import](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html#understanding-pyinstaller-hooks)

Comment: But your method is not working. I am getting the same error with that way.

Comment: Have you try to add the three import mentionned in your answer?