# Pyinstaller - Tkinter "AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI71562\tcl" not found" Error

Tags: python, tkinter

no matter how simple my tkinter apps are, pyinstaller continues failing on all executables.

Sadly, when I compile it via pyinstaller (i tried: --noconsole --onefile AND --noconsole --hidden-import --onefile tkinter) it gives out following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 25, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "C:\Users\juana\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI71562\tcl" not found.
```

What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with Pyinstaller with tkinter app on python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528665/problems-with-pyinstaller-with-tkinter-app-on-python-3-5)

Comment: No but i fixed it with deinstalling python 3.10 and installing python 3.9.2